# .NET Multiline TextBox - Set number of lines

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I want to be able to set the number of lines in a multilined `TextBox`.

I've tried the following:

```
int initHeight = textBox1.Height;
textBox1.Height = initHeight * numOfLines;
```

But this makes it too large when `numOfLines` gets large. So then I tried this:

```
float fontHeight = textBox1.CreateGraphics().MeasureString("W", textBox1.Font).Height;
textBox1.Height = fontHeight * numOfLines;
```

But this was too small when `numOfLines` was small, and too large when `numOfLines` was large.

So I'm doing SOMETHING wrong... any ideas?

Comment: The lines are really controlled by the number of characters allowed in the control.  Check MaxLength in the properties of the textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would set the exact `Width` & `Height` of your multi line Textbox:

```
 Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font);
 textBox1.Width = size.Width;
 textBox1.Height = size.Height + Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Font.Size);
```

Comment: So why do I need to add the font size?

Comment: Adding the font size sets the Textbox height, otherwise last line never gets visible properly.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font);
textBox1.Width = size.Width;
textBox1.Height = size.Height;
```

This was from [C# Resize textbox to fit content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048455/c-sharp-resize-textbox-to-fit-content)

Comment: This doesn't really seem to work so well. Its just a tad off.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing should work, but you need to set the [`MinimumSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.minimumsize.aspx) and [`MaximumSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.maximumsize.aspx) I am not 100% positive, but I think this constraint will still hold if height is set via code

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx):

> To obtain metrics suitable for adjacent strings in layout (for example, when implementing formatted text), use the MeasureCharacterRanges method or one of the MeasureString methods that takes a StringFormat, and pass GenericTypographic. Also, ensure the TextRenderingHint for the Graphics is AntiAlias.

As such, you should use one of these overloads, such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142109.aspx), which allow you to specify `StringFormat.GenericTypograpic` to get the required size.

Try this:

```
float fontHeight;
using (var g = textBox1.CreateGraphics())
    fontHeight = g.MeasureString("W", textBox1.Font, new PointF(), StringFormat.GenericTypograpic).Height;
```

Comment: While this seems to give a more accurate result... It kind of looks like it needs to be rounded anyways...

Comment: @Andrew It shouldn't - there are other comments in there, such as making sure that the graphics are set to AniAlias, etc.  If you do that, you should, in theory, get the proper height.