# Change TextBox width when index has changed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have a project and i want to resize the textboxes width so as to fit to the text i set.

I tried the code below but not all of the text is showing. Specificly, i have a List named **input** where i save the txt file i read, line by line,  using stream reader.

Then i want to resize the textbox width to show all the line.
I'm not allowed to use a richtextbox, so i need your help!!

```
 for (int count = 0; count < input.Count; count++)
            {
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.Name = "text_Box_line" + count.ToString();
                tb.Text = input[count].ToString();
                Point p = new Point(100, 30 * count);
                tb.Location = p;
                Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(tb.Text, tb.Font);
                tb.Width = size.Width;
                tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length;
                tb.ScrollToCaret();

                this.Controls.Add(tb);
            }
```

for example, the text i want to show is:

"[00400000]   00000000          main"

and the shown text is

"   00000000        main"

Comment: I have removed the `mongodb` tag here. I don't think the question has anything to do with `mongodb`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Resize textbox to fit content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048455/c-sharp-resize-textbox-to-fit-content)

Comment: Do you want to create a textbox foreach line of your input?

Comment: just out of curiosity....why?

Comment: Exactly! i want to create a new textbox foreach line of my list<string> 
@Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason you can't use the built in autosizer?

```
for (int count = 0; count < input.Count; count++)
            {
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.Name = "text_Box_line" + count.ToString();
                tb.Text = input[count].ToString();
                Point p = new Point(100, 30 * count);
                tb.Location = p;
                tb.AutoSize = True;
                tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length;
                tb.ScrollToCaret();

                this.Controls.Add(tb);
            }
```