# Dynamically shrink font in multi textbox

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I have a user form with a textbox that contains multiple lines of text. I want the fontsize of the textbox to change dynamically based on the amount of writing in the textbox so the fontsize is at a maximum, something like a ItWillGrow property. I know the following can be used for a textbox containing a single line with an on change command

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(...)
dim scale as single
Me.FontSize = 10 'default text size
scale = Me.TextWidth(Me![MyTextStr]) / Me![MyTextStr].Width
If scale >= 1 then
     Me![MyTextStr].FontSize = 10/scale
Else
     Me![MyTextStr].FontSize = 10*scale
End If
End Sub
```

Is there something similar for a multi line textbox?

Comment: As per the API : `the default size of a TextBox will be in accordance with the font size even if you resize the TextBox. To get a consistent size for your TextBox, set its Multiline property to true.` [So you want to resize the textbox font to fit the contents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048455/c-sharp-resize-textbox-to-fit-content)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering based on the [VB code of API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4xdbe66%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):-

```
Private Sub MeasureText1(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    Dim text1 As String = "Measure this text" 
    Dim arialBold As New Font("Arial", 12.0F)
    Dim textSize As Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text1, arialBold)
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text1, arialBold, _
        New Rectangle(New Point(10, 10), textSize), Color.Red)

End Sub
```

I **missed** out your tags are for VBA not VB. Let me update with a workaround.