# vb.net Autosize Multiline Textbox height with wordwrap

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to make a fixed width textbox in a windows forms app in visual studio 2013 that will begin as a single line in height and expands as the user types and either the text wraps (wordwrap) or when the user pushes enter to create a new line. Ideally i would like to set a max height at which point a vertical scroll bar would be added. Also, the textbox should shrink when the user deletes content as well.

Would also much prefer to be able to use a rich text box however I would settle for a regular text box.

Please tell me it doesn't require some crazy workaround to do what should be relatively easy.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I know how to increase the size of the textbox. I need to know how to retrieve the height of the text inside the textbox otherwise i have no idea how large to make it.

Comment: See [C# Resize textbox to fit content](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8048455/719186)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a rich textbox then try adding this to your form's class - remembering to rename all the bits that say"RichTextBox1" to the name of your richtextbox name

```
Private Sub richTextBox1_ContentsResized(sender As Object, e As contentsResizedEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.ContentsResized
    RichTextBox1.Height = e.NewRectangle.Height + 12
End Sub
```

The only downside of this is that whatever size you initially chose for your richtextbox, it will be ignored as  the above event fires when the form loads

Comment: Thanks David, I'm not concerned about the size when loading, I plan to set that on load anyways. I got a regular textbox to size the way i would like. I'll implement your solution with a richtextbox.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Height = 
        TextRenderer.MeasureText(
            TextBox1.Text,
            TextBox1.Font,
            New Size(TextBox1.ClientSize.Width, 1000),
            TextFormatFlags.WordBreak
        ).Height
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
txtBox.Height = txtBox.Font.Height * (txtBox.Lines.Count + 1)
```

Comment: This magically worked for me. But maybe a little bit of explanation. Why lines count + 1?